# How to install self signed .pem certificate for an application in OpenSuse?

Tags: opensuse, openssl, ssl, certificates

Recently my workplace has updated the internet usage policies and imposed a Sophos security layer to monitor the traffic.

I am trying to clone a git repo (using `git clone` command) but getting this following error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

This is "as implied" the Certificate problem. How can I get this working?

**UPDATE1:**
Certificates are correct as they successfully work with browser(firefox) the question is to how to use these certificates to enable git SSL verification.

**UPDATE2:**

Copied the certificates taken from Firefox *(export from **Firefox > Preference > Privacy & Security > Certificates > View Certificates**)* to `/etc/ssl/certs`.

Executed as root `c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs` and `git config --system http.sslCAPath /etc/ssl/certs`.

Produces following response. the cloning starts and dies mid-way

```
Cloning into 'openssl'...

remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.

remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.89 MiB | 16.11 MiB/s   

fatal: early EOF

fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Sophos security act as [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) so you should disable check of SSL/TLS for this repo. Using the [answer from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622001/2908599):

> To disable TLS/SSL verification for a single git command try passing
>   `-c` to git with the proper config variable, or use Flow's answer:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://example.com/path/to/git
```

> To disable SSL verification for a specific repository If the repository
>   is completely under your control, you can try:

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

The problem is not in to the certificate because this certificate (self-signed) is on your machine (in Sophos security software). You can prove it by stopping Sophos software (if you have permissions) and try again (the same will be with browser)

To install this certificate (if browser accept it) open browser, point it to SSL/TLS site, click on the left site and download the certificate (in PEM format). Then copy the file in `/etc/ssl/certs` and exec (eventually) `c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs`

You can try also to exec

```
git config http.sslCAInfo /etc/ssl/certs/<self-signed certificate>.pem
```

or

```
git config --system http.sslCAPath /etc/ssl/certs
```

to make git to accept this certificate

You can also do some things by hand. Search for `config` file in `.git` directory. And add in section `[http]` those lines:

```
[http]
sslCAInfo = /etc/ssl/certs/<certificate>.pem
sslCAPath = /etc/ssl/certs/<certificate>.pem
sslCert = /etc/ssl/certs/<certificate>.pem
```

Comment: The answer was most obviously MITM...what I used to say to my trainees, was, more important than using the tools, is knowing what they do. The answer does have the correction, but does not explains very well *why* it affected the operation and that contrary to the OPs question, there is not really "a certificate" problem per se. +1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, you are correct. But if I explain all, where is the place for OP to think? Nevertheless will add few words about why this is not certificate problem :)

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov. I have seen this answer and it does work. And I agree that Certificates are not the problem. Though I am looking for an answer how to put the Sophos provided certificates instead of default certificates. I believe the "IT team" of the organisation only knows to fix the browser SSL problem (which they did on my PC). but apart from this no other handshakes are going through.

Comment: @RomeoNinov  I have updated the question.

Comment: @RC0993, please check my updated answer

Comment: @RomeoNinov I tried this. It didn't work. I tried for bot `.crt` and `.pem` certs *(exported from **Firefox > Preference > Privacy & Security > Certificates > View Certificates**)*. I am still facing the same error. Just thinking - The title of this post should be **"How to authenticate MITM certificate for git"**

Comment: @RC0993, I edit my answer, please check and try

Comment: Tried `git config http.sslCAInfo`, `http.sslCAPath` and `http.sslCert` all, but getting the same error. Can you check *somehow* the sophos certificate from firefox is taken the way I mentioned? If not, then how will I get it? Is there some naming convention to save the `.pem` files in `\etc\ssl\certs\`

Comment: @RC0993, I can't check Sophos, you can. I describe it in the answer how to get the certificate. And no, there is no naming convention for certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I checked the certificate from firefox as in the comment above is the same as given by the Sophos *(so that is valid)*. Although there is no visible effect on the behaviour of the problem  after copying the *certificate.pem* to *\etc\ssl\certs*. Did `c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs` as root. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RC0993, this is quite strange behavior for me. I edit my answer with one more command, please check and try

Comment: @RomeoNinov Would this `/path/to/cacerts` be `\etc\ssl\certs` ? or `/var/lib/ca-certificates/pem/` or something else...?

Comment: @RC0993, its `/etc/ssl/certs` (if this is the place where you copy PEM file with self-signed certificate), I edit my question

Comment: @RomeoNinov OK! this is interesting... Please check the updated post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88941/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-rc0993).

Comment: **AFTER our chat discussion - Observations:** the `[http]
sslCAInfo = /etc/ssl/certs/<certificate>.pem
sslCAPath = /etc/ssl/certs/<certificate>.pem
sslCert = /etc/ssl/certs/<certificate>.pem` **doesnot have influence** on the working. but before `git config --system http.sslCAPath /etc/ssl/certs` command , need to run `git init` once  in the folder where you want to clone the repo.